# visual basic 2010 windows form application read excel file values into array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I will not insult the real programmers here by calling myself a programmer; I am an amateur at best. Now to the problem at hand:

I am writing a program that will allow users at an emergency operations center quickly login and handle radio traffic and other data. This software will not be handling any sensitive information so data confidentiality is not a concern. Integrity and reliability are, however. There will be multiple instances where this program needs to read from some data source that can be edited outside the program and the file simply copied into place when updates are made (I'll handle that part). We have chosen Excel since it is laid out in a table natively and xlsx files are easily maintained by software on nearly every platform.

What I want to do is this: When the main form opens, I want it to call a public sub in `Module1` (since other forms may need to use this sub as well) and open file `Facilities.xlsx` as read only. There are two columns: A contains the type of facility (Hospital, EOC, Field Command) and B contains the facility name (Greenville Memorial, Spartanburg County EOC), and so on. The number of rows will change as facilities are added and deleted, I'll handle update distribution though. Another excel file, `Personnel.xlsx`, will have more columns and again an unknown number of rows.

What I need to do is A) Determine the size of the array to be populated, including the number of dimensions needed as this will change with the number of columns and rows, and B) read the data into the array for further processing by decision structures or eventual writing to another excel file for other purposes. With all intents and purposes the array should be As String since all values I'll be dealing with will be strings.

I have found dozens of examples, many of which work with a fixed range (A1:B38) and similar, and others that use ADO or even one that somehow brings SQL into this mix, and others that are so incomplete I cannot even determine how they fit into other examples. This code needs to be small, simple, and lightweight, and just needs to read the data from the file into an array. All of the data will be strings so no fancy calculations or other concerns.

As of right now I do have the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library and the Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library (I guess the Office tagged along with Excel) COM references, and in Module1 I have:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

to help ease up references to the namespace.

To date I've tried more than a dozen different examples and have some runtime crashes, some failures to read any data, and some that produced errors that wouldn't allow the build. I'm at a loss and coming close to abandoning Excel to other sources that are less reliable. I really do need some help with this one. If there is a code-light, resource sparing solution please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with xslx file don't use Microsoft.Office.Interop, you don't need it. Look OpenXml libraries (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) or you may try with koogra (http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/)

If you want to use interop this code may help you:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\temp_10\sample1.xlsx");
        Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
        Range excelRange = ws.UsedRange;

        List<string> rows = new List<string>();

        for (int i=1;i<=excelRange.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            string r = "";
           for (int k=1;k<=excelRange.Columns.Count; k++)
           {
               r += (excelRange.Cells[i, k] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value.ToString();
               r += ";";
           }
            rows.Add(r);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the different angle of looking at this. Two things I need to consider: Are the OpenXML Libraries lighter on resources, and are they lighter on code? I have pulled the links you provided, and I will comment out my current code and try some of these examples. I am still having, and likely will still need help with, dealing with the arrays. First, getting the data into the string arrays, second, being able to use one dimension as a condition to extract the strings on the second dimension in a two-column, variable rows (around 40) two dimensional array.

Comment: I've been looking into this solution, but I don't think it's going to work for me. MSDN says that openxml libraries are 2013 or later, and I'm not that far up. I'm using visual studio 2010 and office 2007 so no go on both counts. Can I get this sdk separately or will I have to go back to Interop?

Comment: I've used OpenXml 2.5 with Visual Studio 2010. The file format xslx is the same for office 2007/2010/2013. I think that you can use it

Comment: After talking to several people that will have involvement with this program and after multiple attempts at obtaining the OpenXML SDK (and receiving security warnings triggered by microsoft.com that forced a server lockdown, VPN disconnect, and the VM shutdown) I have decided that, while this is an elegant solution, I do want to continue with the Interop solution for reasons of compatibility and (apparently) security. Until I can work out the OpenXML SDK problems, is there a simple solution to read a dynamic number of columns and rows into a string array?

Comment: I don't know what security problem you have encountered, i've downloaded the installer from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425. The simple solution for read, is using the interop? And the file format is alway xslx?

Comment: I've added a basic and very simple interop example

Comment: I have tried your link and received a 502 error from Microsoft. I will try contacting them directly for some solutions to this (I will also try opening these links in Internet Explorer in a VM to see if MS is boycotting Firefox lol). Files are all .xlsx and should be unless there is an unforseen compatibility issue. I will try your solution and should be able to find code to convert to an array of type string or some way to populate the combobox straight from the object. I tried to upvote this and you but lack the rep, if someone wants to upvote this please do and thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes i get 502 error too, sometimes the link work

Comment: I am having trouble with the following:
`object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
            XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)`
Object is a class type and cannot be used in an expression.
May be my fault for not being more specific. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, program is Visual Basic Windows Form Application using the .NET Framework 4. Maybe something in this setup is conflicting with your code suggestion?

Comment: I've modified my example, hope this can help you. I'm writing in c#, on this computer i don't have installed the vb part of visual studio

Comment: I tried your example, I got several design time errors and build errors. There is obviously something on my end that is not right, and I am not sure on what level that problem exists. Just to be safe, I will dump that entire VM and install a fully clean Windows 7 Ultimate OS, Office 2007, and VS2010. I'll run updates then sever its network connectivity (which unfortunately means it cannot access the secure source archive on the server so I'll likely be rebuilding from scratch. I will start early with the Excel functionality and try again with the OpenXML SDK as well. Thank you for your help :)